# Database not working after integrating Open in... from mail app dunctionality in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, database

I am using database to store login credentials. Once the user logins in to my app I am validating credentials and storing in database. When the user opens the app second time I am retrieving credentials from data base and asking user to continue with same credentials. Once the user switches the user I am deleting credentials in database and adding new credentials. This process is working fine for me.

I have integrating 'Open in...'(mail app) functionality in my app. When the user opens a document in my app from mail app, then the database is not working. Means I am not able to add new credentials or delete the same credentials. 
 can anyone please tell me what is the problem and how to solve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can you please let me analyze your

```
- (BOOL)application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
```

and

```
- (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

So that i can easily figure out whats the actual problem. I think you are doing the checking for user credentials from the `- (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.